# How to pass command parameters with arguments (for e.g --param1=arg1) to Docker container run command in Synology DSM

Tags: docker, synology

I need to pass a command parameter with arguments in the style of `--param1=arg1` to the run command of a docker container in Synology DSM. The docker application version in the package center is `17.05.0-0401`.

On choosing a docker image and opening the `Create Container` window, I found the configuration for the command by going through the following steps:

1. Click on the `Advanced Settings` button
2. Click on the `Environment` tab
3. Fill in the `Command:` value under `Execution Command` section (For e.g, `execname --param1=arg1`

However, I received the following error when creating the container.

```
Run command format error.
```

Comment: Very helpful Q&A, but it's probably better-suited for ServerFault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I am self documenting my own question in hope of helping others as surprisingly this question / issue was quite obscure to resolve.**

While testing by trial and error, I discovered that the `=` character needs to be escaped with a backslash `\`.
Therefore, the following command as per the question example will work correctly, `execname --param1\=arg1`.